# MacBook randomly types incorrect letters when using built in keyboard

Tags: keyboard

This is weird, but my MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2018) has started incorrectly typing some letters when using the built in keyboard. Sometimes the letters go into the text in the incorrect order, or get missed, or sometimes get duplicated.

For example, i typed the following random text as a test and put square brackets around everything that didn't type correctly.

```
This is a document where i expect to use the letter e a lot of[f] times to check 
i[ff] the document ends up with letters in the wrong place especially where there 
are quick keys typed in succession for example the lett[re] E and the lett[re] r may 
[ee]nd up transposed and sometimes a lett[re] may get entered multiple 
times like the letter [ee] and the letter r and sometimes the letter s as well, 
we also sometimes mis[] a letter such as when we type ss or tt.
```

The strange thing is, it's often the same letters, e.g. the letters S, E, and T and F but that may be due to how commonly they are typed.

This doesn't happen when using an external keyboard and only started suddenly in the last couple of weeks. Could this be a hardware fault, or software fault? The only thing I can think of that has recently changes as I recently acquired an MX Keys keyboard about 2 months ago (which works fine) but this problem even occurs when the keyboard is not connected and powered down.

Comment: I think a screenshot would be best in this case. I am having a difficult time wrapping my head around what you are saying. I think the SE formatting is making it more difficult than it should.

Comment: The text just is an example of what ends up in a document when i type, the issue is that it isn't what i typed. e.g. I enter the keys "e", "n" and "d" and the "e" gets duplicated so the text appears as "eend" or frequently i enter "e" and "r" bit the get transposed and come out as "r" and "e".